# Javascript deny submit not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have this code that should deny form submission if a input validate function returned false. I am not sure what i did wrong on this

```
<script>
function validateName(x){
      // Validation rule
      var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9']{3,}$/;
      // Check input
      if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){
        // Style green
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#ccffcc';
        // Hide error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{
        // Style red
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#e35152';
        // Show error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false;
      }
    }
function validateForm(){
      var error = 0;
      if(!validateName('name')){
         error++;
      }
     if(error > 0) {
         return false;
     }
    }
</script>
```

And my html goes like this

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
Username
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" onblur="validateName(name)" maxlength="12"/>
<p class="inputdesc" align="center">(Between 8-12 characters.)</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register"/>
<input type="reset" value="Clear Form"/>
</form>
```

The code still allows submit even if the input text isn't valid.

Comment: What does your debug console tell you?

Comment: im not using any IDE.. is there something i could test this online quickly to give the debug console message to you?

Comment: Nope, it's a console in your browser. Press F12 and refresh (on most browsers, on Windows)

Comment: it only said
`TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Comment: and that error was only meant for stying.

Comment: If I remove this, it works for me: 'document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";' and change 'name' to 'username'.

Comment: That error is a javascript error, css doesn't give errors (that would be something!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is take advantage of passing the object on the function instead. Example:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" id="form">
Username
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" onblur="validateName(this)" maxlength="12"/>
<p class="inputdesc" align="center">(Between 8-12 characters.)</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register"/>
<input type="reset" value="Clear Form"/>
</form>

<script>
var okay = false;
function validateName(e){
  // Validation rule
  var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9']{3,}$/;

  // Check input
  if(re.test(e.value)){
    // Style green
    e.style.background ='#ccffcc';
    // Hide error prompt
    // e.style.display = "none";
    okay =  true;
  }else{
    // Style red
    e.style.background ='#e35152';
    // Show error prompt
    e.style.display = "block";
    okay =  false;
  }
}

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    if(okay == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.submit();
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: is this one not lacking a parenthesis? `document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){`

Comment: no @Gelo103097 it does have below, right before the closing `</script>`, i just used an anonymous function instead

Comment: its still not working, im not sure why.. im having this error on my console `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Comment: @Gelo103097 what are you doing, you can just paste this and it will work, here is a [DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vKpEo4)

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for name, not username

```
if(/^[A-Za-z0-9']{3,}$/.test(document.getElementById(x).value) {
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}


function validateForm(){
  var error = 0;
  if(validateName('username') == false){
    error++;
  }
  if(error > 0) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

form

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
  Username
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onblur="validateName(name)" maxlength="12"/>
  <p class="inputdesc" align="center">(Between 8-12 characters.)</p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register"/>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear Form"/>
</form>
```